# Django 1.9 and django.contrib.auth

Tags: django, django-models, django-settings

I don't have `django.contrib.auth` in `INSTALLED_APPS`, and I don't want to do it because I'm using a custom user model and I don't need none of the builtin `User`, `Group` and `Permission` models.

I was hoping this was possible in Django 1.9, as the docs state in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/ under the `django.contrib.auth` section that:

> `AbstractBaseUser` and `BaseUserManager` were moved to a new `django.contrib.auth.base_user` module so that they can be imported without including `django.contrib.auth` in `INSTALLED_APPS` (doing so raised a deprecation warning in older versions and is no longer supported in Django 1.9).

However, as of now I can't import anything from `django.contrib.auth` without raising errors. No middleware or form can be imported. I have to either add `django.contrib.auth` to `INSTALLED_APPS` or don't use anything from that module.

Whenever a model in `django.contrib.auth` is indirectly imported I get the classic error that: `whatever_model_was_indirectly_imported` doesn't declare an explicit `app_label` and isn't in an application in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

**EDIT:** Including last part of the traceback:

```
...
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.backends import RemoteUserBackend
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 38, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 102, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.auth.models.Permission doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

Any workarounds?

Comment: What errors, specifically, do you get when trying to import other modules?

Comment: Whenever a model in `django.contrib.auth` is indirectly imported I get the classic error that: <whatever model>  doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Sure, but what's the traceback? That will point you right to where the models are imported.

Comment: I know where the error is... it's when it attempts to import `AuthenticationMiddleware`, if I comment that line, all good. In order to migrate I had to copy/paste all forms from `django.contrib.forms` I was using, but honestly, I can't be copy/pasting even the middlewares.

Comment: The `middleware` module does not import models directly. If it's caused by Django, and not by a third-party app, can you post the full traceback and/or create a ticket on https://code.djangoproject.com/newticket?

Comment: Check my edited question. I just didn't think this could be reportable as a bug, I mean, there is an explicit intention in allowing importing stuff from `django.contrib.auth`

Comment: Well, one workaround is to simply add it to the installed apps and not use it.

Comment: @knbk Unfortunately, "the middleware module does not import models directly" is not correct in Django 1.9.5: `django.contrib.auth.middleware` imports `django.contrib.auth.backends` which then imports `django.contrib.auth.models.Permission`. Also, the [ModelBackend](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L7) states in its docstring that it "authenticates against settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL", but then it uses the `Permission` model, even though I haven't referenced any permission/group related classes from my custom model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the only workaround as of now is including `django.contrib.auth` in `INSTALLED_APPS` and ignoring the three tables in database.

Comment: You still need django.contrib.auth as an installed app if you have other dependencies/imports from it. It's _just_ for AbstractBaseUser and BaseUserManager that you don't need it anymore.

Comment: And it's just not nice. Thanks for keeping it up.